# CSS Fixed Property Relative to Parent/Window based on Left Property

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I have two floating menus. When scroll down, their position is set to `fixed` so that their `top` and `left` is relative to the window. I set their `left` property to `0` they stick to the window as expected. However, when I set it to `1` or any larger number they stick to their containers.

[`Left` set to 1](http://jsfiddle.net/bugan/6eQ86/)

[`Left` set to 0](http://jsfiddle.net/bugan/qa2VV/)

Anybody has any idea why?

Comment: what do you need to achieve? you cannot just have `left: 1;` if you have `left: 0` you don't need to specify an unit, but if your left > 0, you need to specify an unit (px, %, ect).

Comment: Both links render the same in Chrome.

Comment: px! I feel so incompetent. Works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use left: 1px instead of left:0.

In CSS if you want to set any property to 0, then you need not to provide unit(px, em etc) but if you want to set it to any non-zero value(1 here), you have to mention a valid unit.

[updated Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6eQ86/3/)

```
.menuFloat{ z-index: 9999; position: fixed; left: 1px; top: 0; width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

bboy said it in his comment already:

`left: 1;` is an invalid value, since it is missing the unit (all length values in CSS need a unit unless the value is 0).

And that’s also the explanation for the behavior you are experiencing here: With absolute or fixed positioning, an element *stays* at the horizontal position it would have in normal flow if it wasn’t positioned at all, if you do not give a value for `left` (so the default value `auto` is applied). And since you used an invalid value, you have de facto not given a value at all.

Answer (score 0):

Final answer:

`left: 0;` - correct

`left: 1;` - incorrect

`left: 1px;` or `left: 1%;` - correct

for values > 0, one should specify an unit.

glad you solved it